# Unable to unistall software in wine

Tags: wine, uninstall

I am trying to unistall a Windows application installed in Wine.  When I run the command:

```
wine unistall - -software
```

it says `uninstall: command not found`.

Comment: Run `wine uninstaller` or the uninstaller exe of the installed program.

Comment: Do you mean `--software`?

Answer (score 2):

Try to run wine uninstaller like Windows "Add/Remove Programs" function with this command:

```
wine uninstaller
```